# Rails plugin to find missing foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-keys

What I have:
 A big rails app using ar 2.3.11 & postgresql 8.4 db

What I need: 
 Any gem/plugin/library that look for entire models with associations and provide me a list of missing foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find it, it shouldn't be hard to implement by yourself, for example as Rake task. You should iterate over all your classes (you need to know model classes before, but maybe there is a way to get list of your models somehow from Rails), call [`#reflections`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflections) on all model class and then extract necessary informations.

But if you'll find already implemented solution, then I'll be happy to check it on my old projects too.